# How to remove the parent div if has only an h3 element and empty content divs

Tags: jquery

I have a div with a class `.tour_head1` and there's always an `h3` element and many `div` with content. I want to check if the `tour_head1` has only `h3` element and divs with no content, then remove the whole div `.tour_head1`

**HTML**

```
<div class="tour_head1">
  <h3>Description</h3>
     <div> <p>&nbsp;</p> </div>
       <div></div>
 </div>
```

**JQuery**

```
$('.tour_head1:has(h3:only-child)').filter(function() {
  return !this.textContent.trim();
}).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to check that there's a nested div that's *not* empty:

```
$('.tour_head1:has(h3)').each(function() {  // :has(h3) may not be necessary
    if (!$(this).find('div').not(':empty').length) {
        $(this).remove();
    }
});
```

**[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/7c8fyprj/)**

To check text values as well (for cases where there are empty child elements present), do this:

```
$('.tour_head1:has(h3)').each(function() {
    let contentFound = false;

    $(this).find('div').each(function() {
        if ($(this).text() !== '') {
            contentFound = true;
        }
    });

    if (!contentFound) {
        $(this).remove();
    }
});
```

**[Fiddle demo 2](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/9w280nk3/)**

Answer (score 0):

try this with jquery remove

```html
<div class="tour_head1">
  <h3>Description</h3>
     <div> <p>&nbsp; some text</p> </div>
       <div></div>
 </div>
 <div class="tour_head1">
  <h3></h3>
     <div> <p>&nbsp; some text 2</p> </div>
       <div></div>
 </div>
 <div class="tour_head1">
  <h3>Description</h3>
     <div> <p>&nbsp; some text</p> </div>
       <div></div>
 </div>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
 $(document).find('.tour_head1').find("h3").each(function(){
  console.log($(this).text());
  if($(this).text() == "" || $(this).text() == null)
  {
    $(this).remove();
  }
});
 </script>
```

Comment: This seems to be removing headings that are empty. That's not quite the target. Also, your chained `find` functions could be combined. Finally, there's no reason to include the `document` selector. That's implied.

Comment: @isherwood no i applied on .tour_head1 children only

Comment: Here's a better demo of what this script does. You can see that the last outer div isn't being removed as requested, and that the empty divs aren't being removed. https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/hzrqagvb/